# How to change many-one relationship to many-many relationship in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a simple catalog for a company on the web. It consists of categories with items in them. They now have some items that fit in two categories and want to show one item in two categories.

At the moment the models looks like this

```
public class Category {
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    /* No reference to no category */
}
```

The database that was generated long ago linked the category from the Item-table. So now if i add an item to two categories on the last i added "counts".

I would like to change this without any data-loss. How would i do this? Note that i can change the database structure how much i like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a back up of the database and forcing a update database with dataloss and using

```
          modelBuilder
            .Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Items)
            .WithMany()
            ;
```

then creating an sql-script to insert the data loss into the right table

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new table

```
ItemCategories 
   ItemID,
   CategoryID
```

and add relationships to the Item and Category tables

then populate this table with the categoryID from each item

ie (in SQL)

```
Insert ItemCategories (ItemID, CategoryID)
select itemid, categoryid from items
```

then remove the CategoryID from the Items table, and regenerate the model

Comment: Ok, i added the table and filled it with data. How do i regenerate the model?

Comment: That depends on how you created the model in the first place. If you have an EDMX diagram, add the new table, and generate...